# Flickity on change event not firing in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, flickity

I'm using Flickity for a carousel component in a Nuxt / Vue project. I have created a custom page dots / navigation for the carousel and it works fine except when I drag / swipe the carousel the current slide index is not updating to also update the custom navigation. Clicking on the actual custom navigation works great and controls the carousel as well as updating the current slide index.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Flickity
      ref="flickity"
      :options="flickityOptions"
      class="carousel-band-cards-row"
      :key="componentKey"
    >
      <div
        class="carousel-cell-card"
        v-for="post in posts"
        :key="post.link"
      >
        <div class="card card-social">
          <a
            @click.prevent="toggleModal(post.link)"
            class="l-card"
            target="_blank"
            style="cursor: pointer"
          >
            <header class="card-body-text pt-3">
              <h3 class="card-title-date">{{ post.date }}</h3>
              <div class="card-summary" v-html="post.text"></div>
            </header>
            <div class="card-link-icon">
              <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="card-image card-image--social">
              <i v-bind:class="post.faicon"></i>
              <span class="sr-only">post.socialMediaName</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Flickity>

    <ul
      class="btn-link-list btn-link-list--slide-controls"
    >
      <li
        class="slide-controls-group"
      >
        <ul class="slide-controls-group-list">
          <li
            v-for="(slide, index) in slideOptions"
            :key="index"
            class="slide-controls-group-item"
            :class="{ 'is-selected': index === currentSlide }"
          >
            <button
              class="btn-slider-control"
              @click="goToSlide(index)"
            >
              <span class="btn-bar"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">{{ slide }}</span>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    posts: {
      required: false,
      type: Array,
      default: function () {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // ----- flickity
      componentKey: 0,
      currentSlide: 0,
      slideOptions: ['Slide 1', 'Slide 2', 'Slide 3'],
      flickityOptions: {
        cellSelector: '.carousel-cell-card',
        accessibility: true,
        setGallerySize: true,
        cellAlign: 'left',
        contain: false,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        watchCSS: true,
        selectedAttraction: 0.01,
        friction: 0.15,

        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: false,
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.slideEventListener();
  },
  methods: {
    goToSlide(i) {
      this.$refs.flickity.select(i);
      this.currentSlide = i;
    },
    slideEventListener() {
      this.$refs.flickity.on('change', (i) => {
        this.currentSlide = i;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in your vue devtools event's tab, nothing?

Comment: @kissu ahhh just figured it out! Should have waiting a bit longer to ask the question! thanks for your input as usual though :)....What happened was the carousel content is being pulled in from an API so we had to force a re render of the carousel component which was happening after the mounted hook. So the slide event was not firing. I added the update lifecycle hook and added the event there and it works.

Comment: You could maybe also `await this.$nextTick()`? To wait for the next tick of the rendering before using your flickity.

Comment: oh cool! I will give that a shot...looks prettier :)